# Projection Maps aren't always PL

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I'm reading Rourke and Sanderson's intro to PL topology and I'm having a hard time. There's a counterexample as to why projection maps aren't necessarily PL. It says that the projection of an arc on to another has a graph that is part of a hyperbola. In the book we have established that a map between polyhedra is pl if and only if the graph is itself a polyhedron. I have tried to find explicit map formulas for such a projection but they all appear to be straight lines. Can you help me see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is to consider the orthogonal projection. Instead, you should consider the *central projection*. For instance, the formula for the central projection with the center $(0,0)$ to the line $x+y=1$ is given by the formula
$$
p(x,y)= \left(\frac{x}{x+y}, \frac{y}{x+y}\right).
$$
I will leave it to you to verify that the restriction of this map to generic vertical (or horizontal) lines is not PL.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give it a try